# In MVC 4, It is not calling correct post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In cshtml file

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "contact-form" }))
```

and In view source file showing as

```
<form action="/" id="contact-form" method="post">
```

Comment: have you checked if there is a method named "contact" in the HomeController.cs class? maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Yes It is there contact method as

Comment: [POST("")]
        public ActionResult Contact(ContactModel contactForm)
        {}

Comment: can you post the controller method code here?

Comment: if the answer below helped, can you please mark that as answer?

Comment: Here, It is posting first post action method and the view source file shows as per given code. not posting exact method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
        [GET("")]
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View(new ContactModel());
    }
```

with

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View(new ContactModel());
    }
```

or with

```
            [GET]
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View(new ContactModel());
    }
```

and It is working

Answer (score 2):

```
(Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "contact-form" }))
```

try this. C# is case sensitive. you've used "contact" in your view and "Contact" in your controller. And I don't think you need the annotation that you've added.

Comment: Still It is having the same problem